# Java generics - naming actual types of actual type

Tags: java, generics, reference

Given an interface like this

```
public interface MyInterface1<T extends MyAbstractClass> {
    ...
}
```

I want to make another interface MyInterface2 taking a MyInterface1 as a generic type and in MyInterface2 I want to reference the actual types of the actual MyInterface1

```
public interface MyInterface2<INTERFACE extends MyInterface1<MYCLASS>> {
    MYCLASS returnInstanceOfMyClass();
}
```

So I want to say that method "returnInstanceOfMyClass" returns the actual T of the actual MyInterface1 given to MyInterface2.

The thing is that I am not allowed to write the following

```
public interface MyInterface2<INTERFACE extends MyInterface1<MYCLASS>> {
```

I am allowed to write

```
public interface MyInterface2<INTERFACE extends MyInterface1<?>> {
```

but then I am not able to reference the actual type of T in MyInterface1 in the method signature in MyInterface2 - because I have given it no name to be used when referencing.

I want to be able to do the following in a type-safe way

```
class MyClass extends MyAbstractClass {
    ...
}

MyClass c = new MyInterface2<MyInterface1<MyClass>>.returnInstanceOfMyClass();
```

No casting to MyClass should be necessary, because it can see that the actual class of MyInterface1 given to MyInterface2 is MyClass, and that is what is returned from returnInstanceOfMyClass.

How to do that?

Comment: You can't instantiate interfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a second generic parameter:

```
public interface MyInterface2<U estends MyAbstractClass, T extends MyInterface1<U>> {
    U returnInstanceOfMyClass();
}
```

Comment: `U extends MyAbstractClass`.